# preg_match find numbers and make calculations in a string

Tags: parsing, numbers, preg-match

I have a string like the following:
"This is my string {83 - 93 + 18}"
and I want with php to find the numbers and make the calculations inside the `{}`
for example in this case is 83 - 93 + 18 = 8

I suppose I should user `preg_match("regular",$string);`

Do you know how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

```
$s = 'This is my string {83 - 93 + 18}';

echo preg_replace_callback('~{([0-9][0-9-\s.+*/]*)}~', function ($m) {
                                  eval('$res='.$m[1].';');
                                  return $res;}, $s);
```

Comment: please could you help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23797093/regex-email-validation-that-allows-only-hyphens-in-the-middle-of-the-domain-and